# For every two decidable languages There is a turing machine that decides if they are equal

Tags: computability, turing-machines, context-free, undecidability

I was wondering if this is true. I already proved that it is true for regular languages and I assume it is similar in context free languages (correct me if I am wrong), but what about languages in R that are not context-free?

Comment: Of course there is such a machine. It's one of two: "always return Yes", or "always return No". We may not know which one, but that's not required. Perhaps you want to ask "Is there a Turing machine which for every two decidable languages decides whether they are equal" (note quantifier order). In which case you need to start with what its input is, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems that are decidable for regular languages become undecidable for context-free languages.

Even the intuitively simple problem $L = \Sigma^*$ is undecidable for context-free $L$, where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of the language. That of course means that equality for context-free language $L=K$ is undecidable too.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the reason for that?
Is it because CFL is not closed under intersection?

Can I prove its undecidability by reduction? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Several proofs concerning undecidability properties for CFL use reduction and Post Correspondence Problem, yes. It is also possible to code computations of TM's as strings and show that the valid computations form the intersection of two CFL, and the invalid computations are a CFL.

Comment: Why can't we use  the structure of a PDA (the encoding) to prove that they are equal? similarly to the way we can compare that two regular languages are? I think there is something I am missing here.

Comment: Finite state automata only have states. Pushdown automata also have stack contents. Equivalence of PDA is undecidable, it is impossible. Equivalence of **deterministic** PDA is decidable, however. Long and winding proof for that result.